# ReactJS product id is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have the problem when I use the Reactjs, I'm really new to Reactjs, so maybe it's a easy problem:

```js
class Product extends Component{
    handleUpVote() {
        this.props.onVote(this.props.id)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className='item'>

                <div className='middle aligned content'>
                    <div className='header'>
                        <a onClick={this.handleUpVote}>
                            <i className='large caret up icon'></i>
                        </a>
                        {this.props.votes}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ProductList extends Component {
    handleProductUpVote(prductId){
        console.log(productId +' was upvoted')
    }

    render() {
        const products1 = Data.sort((a,b) => (
            b.votes-a.votes
        ));
        const products=products1.map((product) =>{

        return (
            <div className='ui items'>
                <Product
                    key={'product-'+product.id}
                    id={product.id}
                    onVote={this.handleProductUpVote}
                  />
            </div>
        )})

        return (
            <div className='ui items'>
                {products}
            </div>
        )
    }}
    export default ProductList;
```

At this line I am getting the error and i cant understand why:

```js
this.props.onVote(this.props.id)
```

Comment: Its saying that TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: Can we see your `products1` data that you are trying to map over?

Comment: const Data=[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Yellow Pail',
    description: 'On-demand sand castle construction expertise.',
    url: '#',
    votes: generateVoteCount(),
    submitter_avatar_url: 'images/avatars/daniel.jpg',
    product_image_url: 'images/products/image-aqua.png',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Yellow Daniel',
    description: 'On-demand paper castle construction expertise.',
    url: '#',
    votes: generateVoteCount(),
    submitter_avatar_url: 'images/avatars/daniel.jpg',
    product_image_url: 'images/products/image-aqua.png',
  }
]

Comment: inside `rerturn` do : `onVote={this.handleProductUpVote || {}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget binding this.

You need to pass the ID as a parameter to your click handler function.

Something like this:

```
class Product extends Component{

    handleUpVote(id) {
      this.props.onVote(id)
    }

    ...


      <Product
        key={'product-'+product.id}
        id={product.id}
        onVote={() => this.handleProductUpVote(product.id)}
      />
}
```

Comment: I tried both the above methods and its still like giving the same error.

Comment: @RickySterling You need to pass the ID as a parameter to your click handler function as well. Have updated my answer for you.

Comment: @RickySterling sorry, edited again. Forget about binding this. You just need to pass the ID as a parameter and also call the function as an arrow function.

Comment: this keyword is like hard to understand

Comment: Yeah so when you were calling `this.props.id`, `this` referred to your class you were calling it in which in your case was your  `ProductList` react class, not the product object you are mapping over. If the answer worked, can you please mark it as the correct answer :) Thanks

Comment: @RickySterling if this answer helped, can you please mark it as the correct? Thanks.